KVM Support for Windows Server 2025
Windows Server 2025 was released in November 2024. I have successfully created a virtual machine for Windows Server 2025 using KVM on Ubuntu, and it is functioning without any issues.
However, I am searching for the latest information on whether KVM officially supports Windows Server 2025. I have already checked the following website, but the information there appears outdated and is not useful for determining the current support status:
https://linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status
Since this is an open-source project, it is possible that official support information might not be available. If anyone has any detailed information regarding this, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share it with me.
Additionally, if you have suggestions for effective keywords or strategies to search for KVM support status, I would be grateful for your advice on how to proceed with further research.
Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Welcome to Server Fault! Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are considered off-topic on serverfault.com. Also please post questions and answers only in English. -  In general, since KVM provides full virtualisation any OS should run and you should do as you already did: simply try. When it works it works. When you want "official" (paid) support with SLA's many commercial Linux distributions will have offerings that include virtualisation based on KVM/qemu/libvirt with a much shorted list of guest OS's they support
